# Can I programmatically "emit" test cases with xUnit?

Tags: xunit

Is it possible to use something other than reflection and the `[Fact]` attribute on a test method to expose tests to xUnit test runner?  For example, I'd like to do something like:

```
[FactSource] // just making this up
public IEnumerable<ITest> GetUnitTests()
{
    yield return new TestCase("test case 1", () => FooAssertion());
    yield return new TestCase("test case 2", () => BarAssertion());
}
```

I've wanted to do this many times to reduce the boilerplate of a function to wrap every single case.  Usually it makes sense, but when I am testing 100 API endpoints it's the difference between a file with 100 lines vs. 400 lines of code.  Also, I have cases where I want to load the tests from a .JSON or .XML file so it would be great if there was another way to load the tests rather than just `[Fact]` or `[Theory]` attributes.

NOTE: `[Theory]` works great for some tests like this, but it doesn't work for loading the cases from a file or for the case I demonstrate above where I am using lambda expressions.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Exude](https://github.com/GreanTech/Exude). It does exactly what you want.